# Golang panic in tls conn Read - only on linux?

Tags: linux, ssl, go

I'm using golang `crypto/tls` to process a custom line-oriented message protocol.

This approach works fine on windows:

```
var fullBuffer string

for {

    // If we're not connected, attempt reconnect
    if this.conn == nil {

        if this.IsSecure() {
            this.conn, err = tls.Dial("tcp", this.GetHostOnly(), nil)
        } else {
            this.conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", this.GetHostOnly())
        }

        if err == nil {
            // log and continue
        }
    }

    // Read from socket into our local buffer (blocking)
    if this.conn != nil {
        readBuff := make([]byte, 4096)
        nbytes, err = this.conn.Read(readBuff)
        if nbytes > 0 {
            fullBuffer += string(readBuff[0:nbytes])
        }
    }
```

Pretty straightforward - and it works fine on win64.

But when i try to run it on Linux (debian 8 - both i386 and amd64 - both golang 1.5 native and 1.6 crosscompiled from windows) i get the following panic:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4ec8b4]

goroutine 8 [running]:
panic(0x8237780, 0x18522030)
    C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x326
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Handshake(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:1023 +0x198
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0x0, 0x18597000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:922 +0x5e
mylib.(*MyConnection).worker(0x18512480)
    C:/gopath/src/mylib/mylib.go:342 +0x200
```

The Read call is failing because it's somehow passing nil to the TLS handshake.

What's going wrong here?

And, why is the problem isolated to linux?

Comment: Please don't use "this", every time a go dev uses "this" or "self", god kills a kitten.

Comment: Except god doesn't exists thus you can use "this" of "self" because everyone knows what it is and will not confuse it with any other variable. Like `t` or `r`, for example, used everywhere even in the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, linux builds are producing the error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

But

- the certificate is valid

  - `crypto/x509/root_unix.go` looks in `/etc/ssl/certs` which is world-readable
  - but `openssl s_client` is hanging on `-showcerts -verify`, pointing to some issue with my OS network configuration
- for some reason the `if` block below is being entered regardless of the error

  - but i was storing it as a `net.Conn` instead of a pointer, so it's not `nil`-able.

Calling this solved, sorry for the noise. Hopefully this debugging story helps someone else in the future

Comment: Well, you never explained what `this` is. Some Go packages, even the sys ones, could return a non-nil type even if there was an error (for example, the `Open` command falling in `that`).. If you wrote `this` yourself, than you'd have to ensure all logic of `that` produces nil.  (PS, see why we don't use `this` and just call it `cert` instead?)